# (Numpy) How to stack 4 arrays into one?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a list of 1000 numpy arrays (32x32) each, so

array.shape = (1000, 32, 32).
How do i best go about stacking the entire list into a 64x64 array for example, so that the result is (250, 64, 64)?
Hereby, the first 4 (32, 32) arrays are concatenated like so:

```
1   |   2
----------
3   |   4
```

This would mean that I end up with 250, 64x 64 arrays.
Can anyone help out?

Comment: reshape to (250,2,2,32,32), swap axes so it is (250,2,32,2,32), and a final reshape.

Answer (score 3):

You can also go over the colon notation here. This should have the same output as if you iterate over the arrays:

```
import numpy as np
large_array = np.zeros((1000, 32, 32))
output_array = np.zeros((250, 64, 64))

# Extract each block 1, 2, 3 and 4 and write to output array
# '::4' select only every fourth array
output_array[:, 0:32,  0:32] = large_array[0::4, ...]  # Blocks: '1'
output_array[:, 32:64, 0:32] = large_array[1::4, ...]  # Blocks: '2'
output_array[:, 0:32,  32:64] = large_array[2::4, ...] # Blocks: '3'
output_array[:, 32:64, 32:64] = large_array[3::4, ...] # Blocks: '4'
```

Comment: IMO second and third  assigning values have to be swapped. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a method that still uses a loop but does not create any new array beside the final one that gets filled iteratively.

```py
#yourlist.shape == (1000,32,32)
new = np.empty((250, 64, 64))
for i in range(0, yourlist.shape[0], 4):
   a, b, c, d = yourlist[i:i+4] # views
   new[i // 4, 0:32, 0:32] = a
   new[i // 4, 0:32, 32:64] = b
   new[i // 4, 32:64, 0:32] = c
   new[i // 4, 32:64, 32:64] = d
```